# How to display log data on ASP.net MVC4 site with AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to webdesign(using ASP.net MVC4/Razor) and sometimes the information on the internet is too much, I have been googleing for 2 hours and I found plenty different answsers for my problem but I got no clue which one is best, so I ll ask it here:

I got a Database (EF code first) and it has a log table that gets inserted from different places. However I want to make a page and on that page it should always show the last 20 rows.

So I googled, and found:

- Micorosoft ajax?
- Jquery Ajax?
- unobtrusive Ajax?
- SignalR with Jquery?
- Websockets?
- Using ajax with templates?

I am sure, there will be some options that are better then others or maybe an option I have not mentioned yet. Could someone please tell me what direction should I dig into to get the thing I want. (I don't want to get all the code, I just need some guidance since I am a bit lost in the too many options +-)

**EDIT**:

I'll specify some more, I know I'll have to make a API to get JSON something like

```
public JsonResult GetLast20LogRows()
{
  ...
  return listoflast20rows; //(as List<DatabaseLog>()) 
}
```

I just don't know the `HTML/Javascript/ajax` par and how to let it refresh the HTML without refreshing whole the page.(Ajax)

**EDIT2:**

Serverside code:

**`ChatBotLog.cs` (EF Code First):**

```
  public class ChatBotLog
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public ServerRegion Region { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

And now I want a .cshtml (razor page) to fetch a method that display the last 20 rows, I' ll make the method fast to get the last 20 rows:

```
public JsonResult GetLastLogRows()
{
     using (var db = new MyDb())
     {
         var listlog = db.ChatBotLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(20);
         return Json(listlog);
     }
}
```

I think that is a method I should make according to what I have read, anyway please tell me if I am wrong, and I still looking for a way to show it on the view, what type of ajax should I use, it does not have to be "real time live" but like refresh data every 5 sec.

Hope you understand better now, where I am stuck.

Comment: could you highlight where you are stuck? You're question is very broad, seems you're asking about the whole front/back dev cycle. **Break if down** first, `Can you fetch the log table from the data base on a page? > Can you fetch from the database >  Can you display some value on an mvc page > Can you write a query to get only the last 20 records from the database` These are separate items, break them down further and you'll get a definite answer on google.

Comment: If you post the code on your server, we can write the client bit. Without out, we'll be coding half blind or writing a tutorial and there are a lot of tutorials out there.

Comment: Updated my question, tell me if you still don t know were I am stuck.

Comment: use ajax, can return html from server or json. If json will need to parse the json into html using javascript, if send html can use jQuery shortcut method `load()` to easily insert remote html

Comment: So Jquery Load method will keep updating ? Doesn t it only call the json method once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved with a so-simple approach:

1- create a jQuery function that will pull the data from your web server
Example:

```
function GetLatestLogEntries()
{
    var latestLogEntries;

    $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "/{RootFolder}/GetLast20LogRows",                   
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (e) {
                     latestLogENtries = e.data;  

                     // here you will need to format the log entries according to your needs, for example
                     $("#divLogContainer").html(latestLogENtries);

                 }
          });
    }
```

2- Put the following code inside your script tag to ensure that it will get executed after all the page elements are loaded

```
$(function(){
       setInterval(GetLatestLogEntries(),5000);
})
```

3- Smile :)

This will execute the **GetLatestLogEntries** function every 5 seconds and your page will get updated by the latest 20 entries

if you need further explanations, feel free to comment over this answer

Hope this helps :)